# Refresh sub form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have form name called A and i have added two form B and C into form A as a sub forms. i wanted to enter the value in subform B. as soon as i enter the value in B form,form C should refresh for show the value from form B.
currently i am using below coding but it doesn't work. can any correct solution?

```
Private Sub nametxt_AfterUpdate()
Dim mydb As Database

 Dim SqlStr1, SqlStr2, SqlStr3, Sqldup As String

 Set mydb = CurrentDb
 
SqlStr1 = "Insert Into Sample (name) Values ('" & nametxt.Value & "')"

mydb.Execute (SqlStr1)

mydb.Close

Me.Refresh

Me.Parent.sub2.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Probably need to first commit record on subform B before requery subform C. Why would two subforms show same data?

Comment: What about my comment for committing record edit first? Still don't understand why 2 forms but if you want it, it should work.

Comment: If form is bound, should not need an INSERT action. For methods of programmatically saving record, review http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as i enter the value in B form,form C should refresh

Then you must use some AfterUpdate event, of the textbox or the form (which will only happen if you save the record). Then this will work:

```
 Me.Parent!NameOfSubformControl.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. above code does not working. no error message.

Comment: Did you save the record? Until saved, Form C knows nothing about the revised data.

Comment: If the form is bound, don't execute a query. Just set `Dirty = False` to save the record.